# $f ( n ) = n ^ { 2 } + \sqrt { n }$. Whether $2 ^ { 2 ^ { f ( n ) } } = \Omega ( g )$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

> Let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f ( n ) = n ^ { 2 } + \sqrt { n }$. Determine whether the following statement is true or false, providing a proof for your answer.
>
> $2 ^ { 2 ^ { f ( n ) } } = \Omega ( g )$, where $g(1) = 1$, $g(2) = 2$, and $g(n) = [g(n - 1)] ^2 + [g(n - 2)] ^2$ for $n \ge 3$.

I think the statement is false as $g(n)$ seems to grow faster, but how can I formulate a proof for that?

Answer (score 0):

The first seven values are
$$
\begin{array}{r|r|r}
n  & g(n) &2^{2^{f(n)}}\\
\hline
 1 & 1. & 16. \\
 2 & 2. & 6.8\times 10^{12} \\
 3 & 5. & 1.02\times 10^{512} \\
 4 & 29. & 1.6\times 10^{78913} \\
 5 & 866. & 9.6\times 10^{47586437} \\
 6 & 750797. & 2.9\times 10^{112995071916} \\
 7 & 5.63697\times 10^{11} & 2.\times 10^{1060547355989709} \\
\end{array}
$$
unless you meant $2^{f(n)}$ there are no doubts. Even in this case $2^{f(n)}$ grows faster